# Inverted Rounded Rectangle Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

How would I draw an inverted rounded rectangle as shown below in Swift using a UIBezierPath? To clarify, I want to ONLY draw the shape in black.

[image: Inverted Rounded Rectangle]

Comment: Draw yourself the UIBezierPath, and use `addArc(withCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)` to make the "rounded" (which is a part of a circle), or use a curve to do so.

Comment: Why only `UIBezierPath`?

Comment: Also, what's the ration between the white and black areas? Or is it a fixed amount of white on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most of us would simply put a white view with rounded corners on top of the black view (it is simpler and it more accurately reflects the visual result), if you really want to draw that shape, create a `UIBezierPath` that consists of the upper left arc, the upper right arc, and the add lines to the two bottom corners. E.g.

```swift
let path = UIBezierPath(
    arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.minY),
    radius: cornerRadius,
    startAngle: .pi,
    endAngle: .pi / 2,
    clockwise: false
)
path.addArc(
    withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerRadius, y: rect.minY),
    radius: cornerRadius,
    startAngle: .pi / 2,
    endAngle: 0,
    clockwise: false
)
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
path.close()
```

There are a ton of ways to render this:

- Create `CAShapeLayer` with this `path` and use that as a mask (which I show below);
- Add this `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer of the view’s `layer`;
- Create a `UIImage` using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, and `fill` that `UIBezierPath`;
- etc.

For example:

```swift
@IBDesignable class BottomView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let path = UIBezierPath(
            arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + cornerRadius, y: bounds.minY),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .pi,
            endAngle: .pi / 2,
            clockwise: false
        )
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - cornerRadius, y: bounds.minY),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .pi / 2,
            endAngle: 0,
            clockwise: false
        )
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor // the color here is irrelevant; only used to define the mask

        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

That yields the following when I (a) add this `BottomView` to my view hierarchy; and (b) set the `backgroundColor` of this view to `.black` (or whatever you want):

[image]

I made this `@IBDesignable` so that I could either add it in Interface Builder storyboard, but you can also add it programmatically, too.

Or you can use this `UIBezierPath` with any of the patterns enumerated above. Whatever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is draw *two* views: the black rectangle, and the top region view with the curves (which I call a "roundyThingy"). So the only interesting part is how to draw the top region view. It too is just a black rectangle, but it has a mask that cuts out the roundy part. So the only *really* interesting part is the mask:

```
    let size = roundyThingy.bounds.size
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
    let image = renderer.image { context in
        UIColor.black.setFill()
        context.fill(.init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        let path = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: .init(origin: .zero, size: size),
            byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
            cornerRadii: .init(width: 12, height: 12)
        )
        path.fill(with: .clear, alpha: 1)
    }
    roundyThingy.mask = UIImageView(image: image)
    roundyThingy.mask?.frame = roundyThingy.bounds
```